# Wordpress site returning fatal error "Cannot redeclare wp_get_server_protocol() (previously declared in /home/...."

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which is returning the following

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wp_get_server_protocol() (previously declared in /home/wryl/public_html/wp-includes/load.php:16) in /home/wryl/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 21

It's not a site i have anything to do with normally but have been asked if i can fix this issue. I've attempted to re-upload clean wordpress files (wp-admin & wp-includes) and made sure all the permissions have been set correctly but still get the above error. I'm a little lost as to what to try next

Comment: please include the contents of `/home/wryl/public_html/wp-includes/load.php`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/2YHkLMr3

Comment: Couldn't seem to add it as code due to the comments but it's not been changed from the original download from wordpress

Comment: Okay, doesn't seem it's an issue in that script. I did some research and seems this could be caused by themes 'requiring' this script rather than using 'require_once' hence the re-declaration of  wp_get_server_protocol. Try disabling any newly installed themes (or plugins? not sure how wordpress works)

Comment: I've disabled the theme by adding an underscore to the theme folder name. This should make the site default to the 2016 theme which is also installed. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have worked